# Get firstweekdaydate in sql server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2012

Hi Friends I Have small doubt in sql server please tell me how to solve below issue

```
Table :  testdate


    date          |weekno
    1/1/2015      | 1
    1/2/2015      | 1
    1/3/2015      | 1
    1/1/2014      | 1
    1/1/2014      | 1
    1/2/2014      | 1
    1/3/2014      | 1
    1/4/2014      | 1
    1/4/2015      | 2
    1/5/2015      | 2
    1/6/2015      | 2
    1/7/2015      | 2
    1/8/2015      | 2
    1/9/2015      | 2
    1/10/2015     | 2
    1/11/2015     | 3
    1/12/2015     | 3
    1/13/2015     | 3
    1/14/2015     | 3
    1/15/2015     | 3
    1/16/2015     | 3
    1/17/2015     | 3
    1/18/2015     | 4
    1/19/2015     | 4
    1/20/2015     | 4
    1/21/2015     | 4
    1/22/2015     | 4
    1/23/2015     | 4
    1/24/2015     | 4
    1/25/2015     | 5
    1/26/2015     | 5
    1/27/2015     | 5
    1/28/2015     | 5
    1/29/2015     | 5
    1/30/2015     | 5
    1/31/2015     | 5
    2/1/2015      | 6
```

based on above data I need to display one more column firstdayofweekwithdate and data look like below.this data for one month but in orgianly table data have 30 years data similary to above data.

```
        date         |weekno  |   Firstdayofweeknodate
        1/1/2015     |  1     | "1   1/1/2015"
        1/2/2015     |  1     | "1   1/1/2015"
        1/3/2015     |  1     | "1   1/1/2015"
        1/1/2014     |  1     | "1  1/1/2014" 
        1/1/2014     |  1     | "1  1/1/2014" 
        1/2/2014     |  1     | "1  1/1/2014" 
        1/3/2014     |  1     | "1  1/1/2014" 
        1/4/2014     |  1     | "1  1/1/2014" 
        1/4/2015     |  2     | " 2  1/4/2015"
        1/5/2015     |  2     | " 2  1/4/2015"
        1/6/2015     |  2     | " 2  1/4/2015"
        1/7/2015     |  2     | " 2  1/4/2015"
        1/8/2015     |  2     | " 2  1/4/2015"
        1/9/2015     |  2     | " 2  1/4/2015"
        1/10/2015    |  2     | " 2  1/4/2015"
        1/11/2015    |  3     | "3   1/11/2015"
        1/12/2015    |  3     | "3   1/11/2015"
        1/13/2015    |  3     | "3   1/11/2015"
        1/14/2015    |  3     | "3   1/11/2015"
        1/15/2015    |  3     | "3   1/11/2015"
        1/16/2015    |  3     | "3   1/11/2015"
        1/17/2015    |  3     | "3   1/11/2015"
        1/18/2015    |  4     | "4  1/18/2015"
        1/19/2015    |  4     | "4  1/18/2015"
        1/20/2015    |  4     | "4  1/18/2015"
        1/21/2015    |  4     | "4  1/18/2015"
        1/22/2015    |  4     | "4  1/18/2015"
        1/23/2015    |  4     | "4  1/18/2015"
        1/24/2015    |  4     | "4  1/18/2015"
        1/25/2015    |  5     | "5  1/25/2015"
        1/26/2015    |  5     | "5  1/25/2015"
        1/27/2015    |  5     | "5  1/25/2015"
        1/28/2015    |  5     | "5  1/25/2015"
        1/29/2015    |  5     | "5  1/25/2015"
        1/30/2015    |  5     | "5  1/25/2015"
        1/31/2015    |  5     | "5  1/25/2015"
        2/1/2015     |  6     | "6  2/1/2015"
```

please tell me how to write query to achive all years related data task in sql server.

Comment: Just select the min date from the table itself where weekno is the same + year matches too.

Comment: HI I tried like   select  a.date,a.weekno ,max(a.date)
  ---+ a.weekno 
   FROM [test].[dbo].[dateinfo] a join dateinfo b
  on a.weekno=b.weekno and datepart(yy,a.date)=datepart(yy,b.date)
  group by a.date,a.weekno but it is not given exact value please tell me how to  achive this

Answer (score 0):

You can easily do this, but you'd have to convert your dates to datetime format using `CONVERT(DATETIME,DATE,1)`. I used SQL Fiddle so they did it for me, I converted them back to US format in my code:

```
;WITH CTE AS (
  SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(8),DATE,1) AS DATE, WEEKNO, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY WEEKNO, YEAR(DATE) ORDER BY DATE ASC) AS RN
  FROM TABLE1)
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(8),A.DATE,1) AS DATE, A.WEEKNO, B.DATE+' '+CAST(B.WEEKNO AS VARCHAR)
FROM TABLE1 AS A
JOIN CTE AS B
ON A.WEEKNO=B.WEEKNO
AND YEAR(A.DATE)=YEAR(B.DATE)
WHERE B.RN = 1
```

SQL Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/75d28/2

EDIT:

Just a note, since you have multiple years, you will need to include the year in your partition.

Comment: If it's helpful, accept the answer and up vote for the rep :)